# How to adjust some fields in hook_profile2_presave

Tags: drupal, drupal-7, drupal-modules

What I am trying to do is prevent hook_profile2_presave from updating the user profile or to be able to adjust some of the fields before they are being saved. I know that I could use validation function, but I am trying to achieve the same effect as used in email_confirm module.

Does anybody know why the following code is not working.

```
function mymodule_profile2_presave($profile) {
    $account = user_load($profile->uid);

    if (isset($_SESSION['switch_with_the_old_profile'])) {
        $profile_old = profile2_load_by_user($account, 'my_profile');
        $profile = $profile_old;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I had to manually set a value for each field in the $profile and now it is working. I did something like this:

```
function mymodule_profile2_presave($profile) {
    $account = user_load($profile->uid);

    if (isset($_SESSION['switch_with_the_old_profile'])) {
        $profile->field_test[LANGUAGE_NONE][0]['value'] = $profile_old->field_test[LANGUAGE_NONE][0]['value'];

    }
}
```